# Why do i get wrong shading like if there are sharp edges that shouldn't be there?

Tags: normals

This propeller i modeled has wrong shading on the tip of the blades, like if there are sharp edges but there aren't. The vertices are all connected, the normals are calculated correctly like u can see in the screenshot. I tried splitting it on the wrong shading line and rejoining them, but even after cleaning by distance the problem is still there. The model is using the auto smooth at 180° so that's not the problem either. Also if it can help, when i try to unwrap it, i get separate islands like if those sharp edges had seams aswell even if they don't. What could it be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YRlg3WGe" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YRlg3WGe/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to delete the inner faces that we can see here, they are messing up with the normals:

[image]

Comment: idk how i didnt think about that, i was starting tot think it was a bug :D thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 faces inside the tips messing all up

Comment: But i want it to be all smooth, i use the 180 max to get the whole object smooth and then i use sharp edged to sharpen only what i want. It's a model for a game so it has to be low poly

Comment: You have 2 faces inside the tips messing all up